# How to set the font-weight of a web font properly?

Tags: css, fonts, typography

This probably is very basic but I am struggling with this question for a long time and I had to try.

Let's say I have available a font 'open sans' with the font-weight of 400

> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

and I set the font-weight to **700** in my css.

I am aware the browser will try to guess the bold version of that font.

My question: is this a good practice in terms of typography for the web?
Of course I could have available the 700 version built-in face of the that font but sometimes I prefer the version the browser provides. Should we only use the browser version in last case or are we free to use the browser version whenever we want without being afraid of a 'artificial' look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you my 2 cents advice, if you need both 400 and 700, then load both of them to keep the real look the creator of the font wanted. And be more cross-browser.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```